# VSTO deployment checking for updates

Tags: c#, deployment, vsto, installshield

I have created a VSTO Add_in for Outlook project in VS 2015, i can run it and install it everything works fine. The issue is when the client tries to install it, an "checking for update" is fired. This happens on my side as well. The client has a proxy/firewall, this is blocking them giving a network issue and check for internet connection etc. Is there a way to disable the checking for updates, so that it doesn't try to connect online. I have changed the update settings on project properties not to check for updates, but it still checks for updates. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a certificate validation problem. Turn this off:

Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Check for publisher's certificate revocation

The check for updates might go away. This is #2 from here: [Resolving performance issues with loading Office add-ins (VSTO add-ins or Shared add-ins)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/05/18/resolving-performance-issues-with-loading-office-add-ins-vsto-add-ins-or-shared-add-ins/)